# Ubuntu PCs are unable to configure with IP address from DHCP server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall, dhcp, dhcp-server

We are trying to setup VLAN network in our institute. We have **Cyberoam firwall (Model CR300iNG)** where we have configured VLAN and DHCP server.
When we connect any Ubuntu PC over VLAN network it is getting DHCP reply with IP address from DHCP server, but unable to configure itself. On the other hand Window PCs are getting IP addresses.
If we connect PCs to non-VLAN port of firewall, Ubuntu as well as Windows machines are getting IP addresses without any issue.

There are two scenarios here:

**Scenario 1**: PCs--> Un-managed Switch --> Non VLAN port of Firewall

**Scenario 2**: PCs --> L2 manged Switch -> VLAN port of Firewall

Output of **tcpdump** command for **Scenario 1** is as follows

`16:36:30.447344 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown), length 300
16:36:30.455838 IP 192.168.0.1.bootps > 192.168.0.83.bootpc: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300`

Output of **tcpdump** command for **Scenario 2** is as follows

```
16:38:37.278831 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown), length 300
16:38:37.279098 IP 192.168.101.1.bootps > 192.168.101.33.bootpc: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

In Scenario 2, Ubuntu machine is getting reply from firewall but it is unable to configure its network.

Help in this regard is appreciated.

Thank you.

**First Edit**

Output of **tcpdump -e** command is

```
(base) phoenix@syndicate:/var/lib/dhcp$ sudo tcpdump -e
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s31f6, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:21:07.710907 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:08.291412 98:aa:d7:00:a8:44 (oui Unknown) > 01:01:c1:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9003), length 60: 
    0x0000:  0100 3676 a000 98aa d700 a844 0100 0400  ..6v.......D....
    0x0010:  33b0 cfeb abe6 41b4 fe0e e885 e8fc f70f  3.....A.........
    0x0020:  f6ea 9e12 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
17:21:08.766464 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:16 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 110: :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
17:21:08.787163 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown), length 300
17:21:09.402505 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:ff:09:ff:c6 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 86: :: > ff02::1:ff09:ffc6: ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, who has syndicate, length 32
17:21:09.626530 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:16 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 110: :: > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
17:21:09.711049 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:10.426658 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:16 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 110: syndicate > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
17:21:10.438533 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:16 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 110: syndicate > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
17:21:10.518698 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:16 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 110: syndicate > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
17:21:10.742201 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:02 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 62: syndicate > ip6-allrouters: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 8
17:21:10.954189 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:fb (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 203: syndicate.mdns > ff02::fb.mdns: 0*- [0q] 2/0/0 (Cache flush) PTR syndicate.local., (Cache flush) AAAA fe80::198e:4764:3d09:ffc6 (141)
17:21:11.002537 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:16 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 110: syndicate > ff02::16: HBH ICMP6, multicast listener report v2, 2 group record(s), length 48
17:21:11.118385 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown), length 300
17:21:11.711151 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:11.859015 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:fb (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 203: syndicate.mdns > ff02::fb.mdns: 0 [9q] PTR (QM)? _nfs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ftp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdav._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdavs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _sftp-ssh._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _smb._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _afpovertcp._tcp.local. (141)
17:21:13.177150 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:fb (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 203: syndicate.mdns > ff02::fb.mdns: 0*- [0q] 2/0/0 (Cache flush) PTR syndicate.local., (Cache flush) AAAA fe80::198e:4764:3d09:ffc6 (141)
17:21:13.291410 98:aa:d7:00:a8:44 (oui Unknown) > 01:01:c1:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9003), length 60: 
    0x0000:  0100 2a78 a000 98aa d700 a844 0100 0400  ..*x.......D....
    0x0010:  71a3 0c72 1a6b ea7e 5048 cc5e 9228 ea26  q..r.k.~PH.^.(.&
    0x0020:  931e 3cc6 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..<...........
17:21:13.711117 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:14.742615 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:02 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 62: syndicate > ip6-allrouters: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 8
17:21:15.711150 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:15.860652 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:fb (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 203: syndicate.mdns > ff02::fb.mdns: 0 [9q] PTR (QM)? _nfs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ftp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdav._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdavs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _sftp-ssh._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _smb._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _afpovertcp._tcp.local. (141)
17:21:17.711177 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:18.291297 98:aa:d7:00:a8:44 (oui Unknown) > 01:01:c1:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9003), length 60: 
    0x0000:  0100 1e7a a000 98aa d700 a844 0100 0400  ...z.......D....
    0x0010:  3fb1 f577 69be 692b a79a dd11 81dc a459  ?..wi.i+.......Y
    0x0020:  076a 7510 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       .ju...........
17:21:18.742061 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:02 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 62: syndicate > ip6-allrouters: ICMP6, router solicitation, length 8
17:21:18.754640 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown), length 300
17:21:19.711257 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:21.711115 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:23.291528 98:aa:d7:00:a8:44 (oui Unknown) > 01:01:c1:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9003), length 60: 
    0x0000:  0100 127c a000 98aa d700 a844 0100 0400  ...|.......D....
    0x0010:  994f 1b43 53be 8868 b4ca 761d fb6f 9ec0  .O.CS..h..v..o..
    0x0020:  afcd ae90 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
17:21:23.711243 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:23.867183 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > 33:33:00:00:00:fb (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 203: syndicate.mdns > ff02::fb.mdns: 0 [9q] PTR (QM)? _nfs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ftp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdav._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdavs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _sftp-ssh._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _smb._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _afpovertcp._tcp.local. (141)
17:21:25.711335 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:27.711301 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:28.291542 98:aa:d7:00:a8:44 (oui Unknown) > 01:01:c1:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9003), length 60: 
    0x0000:  0100 067e a000 98aa d700 a844 0100 0400  ...~.......D....
    0x0010:  1e4d 6140 6f64 d89f 26c8 e481 7351 deed  .Ma@od..&...sQ..
    0x0020:  04f8 0b4b 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ...K..........
17:21:29.231844 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:0e (oui Unknown), ethertype LLDP (0x88cc), length 156: LLDP, length 142: SW1
17:21:29.711327 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:29.855733 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown), length 300
17:21:31.711399 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
17:21:32.266665 e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from e0:d5:5e:83:84:00 (oui Unknown), length 300
17:21:33.291680 98:aa:d7:00:a8:44 (oui Unknown) > 01:01:c1:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype Unknown (0x9003), length 60: 
    0x0000:  0100 fa7f a000 98aa d700 a844 0100 0400  ...........D....
    0x0010:  3ddc 5ed1 301d 3e95 e5ed 3539 35a6 c701  =.^.0.>...595...
    0x0020:  7dc6 4f88 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       }.O...........
17:21:33.711370 98:aa:d7:00:a8:49 (oui Unknown) > 01:80:c2:00:00:00 (oui Unknown), 802.3, length 39: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1w, Rapid STP, Flags [Proposal, Learn, Forward, Agreement], bridge-id 0000.98:aa:d7:00:a8:44.8005, length 43
```

**Second Edit**

Last few lines of DHCP client log file (journalctl -t dhclient)

```
May 01 17:31:45 syndicate dhclient[25110]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.83 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3c97cfb6)
May 01 17:31:48 syndicate dhclient[25110]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.83 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3c97cfb6)
May 01 17:31:55 syndicate dhclient[25139]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.83 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3a095824)
May 01 17:31:58 syndicate dhclient[25139]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.83 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3a095824)
May 01 17:32:06 syndicate dhclient[25139]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x860fbc19)
May 01 17:32:09 syndicate dhclient[25139]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x860fbc19)
May 01 17:32:15 syndicate dhclient[25139]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x860fbc19)
May 01 17:32:25 syndicate dhclient[25139]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x860fbc19)
May 01 17:32:40 syndicate dhclient[25219]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.83 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x20828109)
May 01 17:32:43 syndicate dhclient[25219]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.83 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x20828109)
May 01 17:32:47 syndicate dhclient[25219]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.83 on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x20828109)
May 01 17:32:54 syndicate dhclient[25219]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x9974ab74)
May 01 17:32:57 syndicate dhclient[25219]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x9974ab74)
```

It seems the client is requesting IP address **192.168.0.83** (which is the last IP assigned by DHCP server when connected as per Scenario 1) to DHCP server which is configured to give IP address in the range 192.168.101.31 to 192.168.101.254. Plese guide how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you show `tcpdump -e` instead? Do the DHCP client's logs indicate that it has received the reply? (Normally there should be _two_ request/reply pairs if rapid-commit is not used.)

Comment: Output of "tcpdump -e" command is edited in my question. There is not DHCPACK packet in DHCP client log.